# how to use tidyeval functions with loops?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe <- data_frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                        group = c('a','b','c','c'),
                        value = c(200,400,120,300))


> dataframe
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id group value
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     a   200
2     2     b   400
3     3     c   120
4     4     c   300
```

and this *tidyeval* function that uses `dplyr` to aggregate my dataframe according to some input column.

```
func_tidy <- function(data, mygroup){
  quo_var <- enquo(mygroup)

  df_agg <- data %>% 
    group_by(!!quo_var) %>% 
    summarize(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
              count = n()) %>% 
    ungroup()

  df_agg
}
```

now, this works

```
> func_tidy(dataframe, group)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group  mean count
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1     a   200     1
2     b   400     1
3     c   210     2
```

but doing the same thing from within a loop **FAILS**

```
for(col in c(group)){
  func_tidy(dataframe, col)
}
 Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `col` is unknown
```

What is the problem here? How can I use my `tidyeval` function in a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use a loop, I think you may have to use character strings for the names.  You'd then have to use something like `!! rlang::sym(col)` within `func_tidy`.

Comment: @aosmith thanks for the input! problem is, I dont want to modify my function. Can I change the way I call the function in the loop?

Comment: I'm talking about modifying the loop, not the function.  You'd use strings in the loop, i.e., `for(col in "group")`  and then the `!! sym` code as above for the second argument of `func_tidy`.  If you add info about the actual scenario you are in, folks may be able to give you other (non-loop) options.

Comment: @aosmith thats pretty neat, thanks! do you mind posting a solution with this? im pretty sure many people are confused by these tidy problems ;-)

Comment: aosmith is right, you'll have to unquote a symbol. Otherwise `group_by()` will see `col` instead of what it contains. Unquoting allows you to change what the quoting function "sees". So you call it like this: `func_tidy(dataframe, !! sym(col))`, assuming that `col` contains a string.

Comment: thats great. thanks. @aosmith please add the answer. I an nutsheel, can you explain to a noobie like me that is the difference between `!! sym(col)` and `sym(col)` ? I knot the difference between these when I use `enquo` but not with a `sym`

Comment: If you supply `sym(col)` to a quoting function, it evaluates it and gets a symbol object. That's an unexpected input in almost every case. That's like writing `sum(quote(myvec))` instead of `sum(myvec)`. On the other hand if you supply `!! sym(col)` to a quoting function, the quoting function evaluates the result of the unquoting (a symbol), which is a proper vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For looping through column names you will need to use character strings.

`for(col in "group")`

When you pass this variable to your function, you will need to convert it from a character string to a symbol using `rlang::sym`.  You use `!!` to unquote so the expression is evaluated.

So your loop would look like (I add a `print` to see the output):

```
for(col in "group"){
    print( func_tidy(dataframe, !! rlang::sym(col) ) )
}

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group  mean count
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1     a   200     1
2     b   400     1
3     c   210     2
```